# How to schedule gitlab-runner pods on worker nodes only?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab

I have 1 question regarding pods scheduling for runner pods in k8s. As I can see, during different jobs It creates pods like runner-xxxx-project-xxxx-concurrent and this pods creating dynamically. How I can configure scheduling (nodeSelector) for this pods only (runner-xxxx-project-xxxx-concurrent), not for runner-gitlab-runner deployment?

Comment: you can check runners.kubernetes section in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerskubernetes-section) and especially `node_selector` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, depending on the way you have installed your master nodes, they usually have a taint `node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule` to avoid scheduling of pods.

```
$ kubectl describe nodes node1
Name:               node1
Roles:              master
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=node1
                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

So if your kubernetes install is conform, there is no need to use a `nodeSelector` to set the node where the pods are going to be scheduled (it is usually a bad practice).

First solution is to taint your master node for no scheduling if not done during install:

```
kubectl taint nodes node1 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Second solution: set label to nodes to use `nodeSelector`

```
kubectl label nodes node1 gitlab-runner=true
```

And use `nodeSelector` to indicate to scheduler you want node with a specific label:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - [...]
  nodeSelector:
    gitlab-runner: "true"
```

As mentionned by [@Nicolas-pepinster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653911/nicolas-pepinster), you can set the label in the  `[runners.kubernetes]` section of our gitlab-runner ([see doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnerskubernetes-section)).

Comment: I am not using kubernetes executor. I am using , let's say , "native" k8s integration with Gitlab (when you add your cluster using UI). Yes, I know about this , but I am testing scaling from 0 and I've created cluster with cluster-autoscaler. And when some job is triggered and pod scheduled I want to have scaled up instance specifically for this job. I n my case, I've tried to configure runner-gitlab-runner deployment, but It will reschedule only  this pod , not runner-gitlab-concurent pods

Comment: Can you update your question with these information ?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to have the correct taint on master nodes to avoid schedule on them